# PayPal subscription doesn't happen

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

This question is not basic so that means i have read some paypal documentation about this.
I have attached an image. The problem is that i make a Paypal subscription and while its active and stating that the next payment should be done next day, it doesn't happen, what could be the problem? BTW I am using the sandbox[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sandbox tends to get delayed sometimes, and payments don't occur exactly when they should.  The production server doesn't have this issue, usually, but it can happen.

From what I can see you've got it setup correctly so it's just a matter of their system kicking in and processing it accordingly.  Not a lot you can do it about it other than wait.

You could post a ticket to www.paypal.com/mts, but by the time they respond the payment will probably go through.

You could also call their tech support line, which you can find by logging in to your PayPal account, click Contact Us, then by Phone, and it will give you separate numbers for general and technical support.  You can let them know what's going on and they may be able to find what's causing the delay and get it fixed.

Comment: three days later seems to process the first payment, you were right. Thanks